# D3 V4 assigning a listener to d3.brushX when the element is first rendered

Tags: d3.js, brush

I want to assign an event listener to the d3.brushX when the element is first displayed.

I am trying the following:

```
var brush = d3.brushX()
.extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
.handleSize(6)
.on("load", fn_test);
```

I get an error in Chrome when this code is run...??  I though that "load" was a very common event.

The functionality that I want is to put the brush in a specific position when the user first views the page.

Answer (score 0):

The brush does not seem to take a "load" event.

But the containing svg element does.  So I put the load event there. And voila..success!